# type or namespace name 'UISceneConfiguration' could not be found

Tags: xamarin.ios, nuget-package

I have a Xamarin.iOS project and it has included a nugget package aswell. When I try to rebuild the project, I am getting 14 errors and those are `UISceneConfiguration`, `UISceneSession` etc could not be found issues. My nugget package is something like `Abcd.SDK.0.9.7.nupkg` and for the iOS project I can see they have set the Assembly name and the Default namespace like below

- Assembly name - SampleiOS(which is the iOS project name).
- Default namespace - ABCD.SDK.Sample.iOS

In my `AppDelegate.cs` I can see the class namespace as my solution name.

What is the cause for these kind of errors and how can I solve this?
Please help me.
Thank you.

**UPDATE 1**

```
<key>UIApplicationSceneManifest</key>
<dict>
    <key>UIApplicationSupportsMultipleScenes</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UISceneConfigurations</key>
    <dict>
        <key>UIWindowSceneSessionRoleApplication</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>UISceneConfigurationName</key>
                <string>Default Configuration</string>
                <key>UISceneDelegateClassName</key>
                <string>SceneDelegate</string>
                <key>UISceneStoryboardFile</key>
                <string>Main</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

**UPDATE 2**

[image]

Comment: Hi , do you contain the `SceneDelegate.cs` file in project ?

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Yes its included in the project

Comment: Okey , I will update an answer , you can have a look for a while .

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First** having a check with project whether contains the `SceneDelegate.cs` file .

[image]

It above is no problem , **then** opening `Info.plist` file with XML Style to check contain the follow code :

```
<key>UIApplicationSceneManifest</key>
<dict>
    <key>UIApplicationSupportsMultipleScenes</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UISceneConfigurations</key>
    <dict>
        <key>UIWindowSceneSessionRoleApplication</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>UISceneConfigurationName</key>
                <string>Default Configuration</string>
                <key>UISceneDelegateClassName</key>
                <string>SceneDelegate</string>
                <key>UISceneStoryboardFile</key>
                <string>Main</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

**Lastly** , cleaning project and rebuilding it !

===============================Update====================================

Finally checked this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/release-notes/13/13.0#requirements) , if need function of iOS 13 , requires in Visual Studio 2019 .Here `SceneDelegate.cs` starts from iOS 13 , and then can run the shared [project](https://github.com/praeclarum/VectorPerf) from *Randi* .

Comment: The XML looks ok,, there is no any difference in XML code segment

Comment: once clean and rebuild, again getting 14 errors. Please check my updated Question

Comment: @Randi Okey , if uninstalling the nuget package , does it build successfully ?

Comment: @Randi You can show the full error logs in question , I will check it .

Comment: I updated the question with the error log screen shot. Pls check

Comment: @Randi Thanks for updating , then check whether modifying code in `SceneDelegate.cs` such as missing `[Register ("SceneDelegate")]` inside it .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204392/discussion-between-junior-jiang-msft-and-randi).